# reading input and creating a dictionary in AngularJs/Typescript

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript

I am a complete newbie to web UI programming and working on a task to read a dictionary from the Web UI and send it to a RESTful service. There should be an "add" button which on clicking opens up two text boxes to enter the key and the value. The user can add any number of key,value pairs.

I am completely lost as to how to begin tackling this. Do I create models which take in the key and value and store an array of such entries?

It will be really helpful if someone can guide me with the basics to achieve this

```
// Model
export class entry {
   key : string;
   value : string;
}

export class KVMap {
   entries : entry[];
}

// controller - has a function to add entry into KVMap
KVMapParam: Models.KVMap
populateKVMap(entry : Models.Entry) {
 // push this entry into KVMapParam



//View
 <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">KVMap</div>
     <div class="panel-body">
         <ul>
             <li ng-repeat="entry in controller.KVMapParam">
                 <input type="text" ng-model="entry.key"/>
                 <input type="text" ng-model="entry.value" />
             </li>
             <li>
                 <button ng-click="controller.populateKVMap()">Add</button>
             </li>
         </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Honestly, what you need is a tutorial, and we don't do tutorials on SO. Search for some AngularJS tutorials on the web; I'm sure there are many.

Answer (score 0):

I got the basic setup working and able to add values to a key value pair in the controller

Model

```
export class entry {
   key : string;
   value : string;
}

export class KVMap {
   entries : entry[];
}
```

Controller

```
KVMapParam: Models.KVMap
populateKVMap() {
 KVMapParam.push(new entry("","")
}
```

View

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">KVMap</div>
     <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
         <table>
             <tbody>        
             <tr ng-repeat="entry in controller.KVMapParam">
                 <td><input class="form-control" type="text" data-content="{{entry.key}} onclick="this.select();" ng-model="entry.key"/></td>
                 <td><input class="form-control" type="text" data-content="{{entry.value}} onclick="this.select();" ng-model="entry.value"/></td>
             </tbody>
           </table>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group>
            <button ng-click="controller.populateKVMap()">Add</button>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Everytime a new key/val is entered I want to check if the key already exists in KVMapParam. I see that we can use ng-change in the "input" tag to detect a change and call an appropriate expression

```
td><input class="form-control" type="text" data-content="{{entry.key}} `onclick="this.select();" ng-model="entry.key" ng-change="controller.checkifKeyExists(entry.key)"/></td>`
```

Based on the outcome of the expression checkifKeyExists() how can I display an error message ?

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. If you have a new question, use the Ask Question button.

Comment: Ok sure.. I will add a new question for this